# Ubuntu 18.04 after update cannot reach outside network only internal

Tags: updates, ping

I am a newbie.  After an update for security etc for version 18.04.3, I cannot access the web from the server.  I have to disable the firewall to connect by SSH using Putty internally. I can enter the server website from outside, but cannot do update for the server or ping to anything outside like msn.com

```
/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
  dhcp4: false
  dhcp6: false
  addresses:
      - 192.168.5.11/24
  gateway4: 192.168.5.1
  nameservers:
    addresses: [192.168.2.1,8.8.8.8,4.4.4.4]
```

The server is sitting in the DMZ orange zone in IPFire.  I have tried to move the server behind the internet modem, but it is the same thing.  Cannot ping outside and cannot retrieve IP address from DHCP Server of the modem.

Here is more output requested

OUTPUT

```
root@Server1:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown

root@Server1:~# sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 0c
       serial: c4:34:6b:57:d0:c5
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.5.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c00000-f7c00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff

root@Server1:~# ls -al /etc/netplan
total 20
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 17 09:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 117 root root 12288 Jul 15 13:44 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   248 Jul 17 09:49 01-netcfg.yaml
```

Bernie

```
root@Server1:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:34:6b:57:d0:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.5.11/24 brd 192.168.5.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c634:6bff:fe57:d0c5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Since you can reach the server using SSH, it has a working, known IP address...so your netplan YAML does not seem to be the issue. Look more closely at your firewall settings.

Comment: Please show output of `ip a`

Comment: Hi. user535733 and Stephen Boston. I have posted ip a above and the firewall is disabled.  The server sits behind another firewall device IPFire, but there is no change for the IPFire.  The cause of the problem is probably due to a security update to the server.  Traffic can come in if initiated from the outside.  Traffic cannot go out if initiated from the inside of the server.  I have tried to put the server behind the internet modem/router, but it is the same.  No change. It cannot retrieve IP address from DHCP Server or contact outside.  Bernie

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`... keep the formatting EXACTLY the same...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses: [192.168.5.11/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.5.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.2.1, 8.8.8.8, 4.4.4.4]
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Note: Make sure that SSH port 22 is open in your firewall. Understand the security ramifications of doing so.

Note: Your machine has a static IP, so it's not using DHCP.

**Update #1:**

Please try this driver...

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install dkms r8168-dkms`

Shutdown the computer and POWER OFF

Reboot

Retry Internet

**Update #2:**

Problem was with the IPFire firewall. Removed bad rule, now it works.

Comment: Hi Heynnema.  

I tried your new netplan.  It is still the same thing.  


DEBUG: 09:49:28.768: enp2s0: setting default backend to 1
DEBUG: 09:49:28.768: Configuration is valid
DEBUG: 09:49:28.769: Generating output files..
DEBUG: 09:49:28.769: NetworkManager: definition enp2s0 is not for us (backend 1)

I still cannot ping outside the network or download.  From the outside, I can login to the webserver and ping to the domain.

Can it be a routing problem?

Bernie

Comment: @BernieYau Data in the comments is difficult to read. Can you please edit your question and add the above output, and also `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `ls -al /etc/netplan`.. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Heynnema.  I am sorry for the bad output. I have added the extra info in the original questions.  It seems copy and paste from terminal is not working well.  I hope you have an answer. Bernie

Comment: @BernieYau Please see Update #1 in my answer. Report back. Also, the trouble you're having with pasting data into your question is, that for most data, after pasting, you select the pasted text, then hit the `{}` icon to format the text into human-readable format.

Comment: Hi Heynnema.  I can not do sudo update, since I cannot connect to the web.  I can go into the webpage of ther server and use the webpage from outside.  Bernie

Comment: Firewall is off. The server is sitting behind another firewall, but I have not change anything with IPFire.  The server was working fine before.  After security updates, it is not.  There are no changes if I have the server sit behind the internet router.  Cannot get ip address from DHCP server or if static cannot access the outside web.  Bernie

Comment: @BernieYau  Oh silly me. Of course you can't do `sudo apt-get update`... you have no Internet! At the GRUB menu, can you please try booting to the oldest kernel that you still have installed? See if that brings the Internet back. Report back.

Comment: Hi Heynnema.  I tried to put the server behind the internet modem/router using a fixed IP.  I was able to connect the internet and do an update as per UPDATE 1.  SILLY me.  It seems something has changed in the last week.  I do not know what, since I have not change any of the firewall rules of IPFire.  I will look into it.  I am sorry to have wasted your time.  Thanks Bernie

Comment: @BernieYau There still may be something wrong with the server. Recent updates have broken ethernet for more than yourself, and it's sometimes intermittent. That's one reason that I asked you to boot to an older kernel. We may still need to install a different ethernet driver. Please do keep me posted.

Comment: Hi Heynnema.  It seems that the IPFire caused the problem.  I am sorry.  I have to delete one rule.  Now it will ping to the outside but not to the internal green zone. Thank you so much for your help. Bernie